# SQL nolock and join

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using a process that inserts data in 2 tables with rowlock, continuously. In the same time I want to use some queries on these tables. As I said the inserts are done with (rowlock) and I use for the queries the isolation level read uncomitted and nolock.

When I use the queries on a single table they work perfectly, but when I try to join the 2 tables I get this error:

**Transaction (Process ID 88) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.**

Meanwhile, if I use the sp_lock procedure I found that the Key lock becomes a tab lock when I perform my queries.

Does anyone know if there is a special relation between (nolock) and join? And if there is how can I avoid it.

**UPDATE:**

```
Insert into tbl1 with (rowlock)
(
 col1,
 col2,
 col3
)
select * from #tbl_temp
```

( this is in an infinite loop and the data from #tbl_temp is always changed. Actualy this is a more complex process but this is the idea.)

```
Insert into tbl2 with (rowlock)
(
 col3,
 col4,
 col5
)

select * from #tbl_temp2
```

In the same time I perform

```
set transaction isolation level read uncomitted

select col1,col2,col3 
from tbl1 with (nolock)  -- works fine


select col1,col2,a.col3 

from tbl1 with (nolock) join tbl2 with (nolock) on (tbl1.col3 = tbl2.col3)
```

-- deadlock

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I posted a sample of my code.

Comment: can you find out deadlock info either from sql logs ( by switching on trace flags) or from reading default extended events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try turning on [READ_COMMITTED_SHAPSHOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) isolation level for your database.

(But be aware that this will put increased pressure on tempDB)